# Querying a Global Secondary Index: 'MissingRequiredParameter: Missing required key

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, dynamodb-queries

I have a DynamoDB table definition like this one:

```
{
"pk": {
  "S": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001"
},
"sk": {
  "S": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001"
},
"year": {
  "N": "2019"
}
"index": {
  "N": "987654321"
}
}
```

Where "pk" is the Partition Key. And "sk" is the Sort Key. If you are wondering why both, pk and sk, have the same value: [Adjacency List Design Pattern](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-adjacency-graphs.html).

I have created a Global Secondary Index on the attribute "index". Which its projections are both keys, pk and sk.

[image]

Now, [following the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html#GSI.Querying) I am querying my GSI like this:

```
        const params = {
                TableName: 'my_table_name',
                IndexName: 'my_index_name',
                KeyConditionExpression: "index = :v_index",
                ExpressionAttributeValues: {
                    ":v_index": {"N": 987654321}
                },
                ProjectionExpression: "pk",
                ScanIndexForward: false
            };
```

I am receiving the following error message: 'MissingRequiredParameter: Missing required key \'Key\' in params\n

Just in case, I am using Node.js 8.10 in Lambda

Comment: Please show more of your code, like the line number that actually throws the error. Are you using `getItem` or `query`?

Comment: @MarkB you gave me the clue about what I was doing wrong. I was using getItem which it is obviously wrong. Query has to be used in this scenario. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, GSIs can have multiple entries for the same GSI primary key + secondary key combination. As a result you cannot use a `getItem()` call to retrieve objects. Queries against a GSI need to either be `scan` or a `query`

This is mentioned in the first few lines of Amazon's documentation about [working with GSIs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html#GSI.Querying)